# jQuery text flip not properly working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I added some text that is being flipped by jQuery `fliptext` and `lettering` libraries. I put them in sliders, the first slide works okay but rest slides have problem with text. how to achieve it?
here's my link
[**Here is working code**](http://gwslider.mythstreet.com/gamerselectmode.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Find A Gamer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.lettering.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/eliptext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <div id="gc">
                    <span class="username">Game username</span>
                    <span class="level">Level: intermediate</span>
                    <span class="wager">Wager
            <span class="count">500</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sp">sp
            <span class="count">45%</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <a href="#" class="accept">accept</a>
                    <a class="decline" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">decline</a>

                    <span class="ring_1"></span>
                    <span class="tickers"></span>
                    <figure class="user">
                        <img src="images/user.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div id="gc">
                    <span class="username">Game username</span>
                    <span class="level">Level: intermediate</span>
                    <span class="wager">Wager
            <span class="count">500</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sp">sp
            <span class="count">45%</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <a href="#" class="accept">accept</a>
                    <a class="decline" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">decline</a>

                    <span class="ring_1"></span>
                    <span class="tickers"></span>
                    <figure class="user">
                        <img src="images/user.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div id="gc">
                    <span class="username">Game username</span>
                    <span class="level">Level: intermediate</span>
                    <span class="wager">Wager
            <span class="count">500</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sp">sp
            <span class="count">45%</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <a href="#" class="accept">accept</a>
                    <a class="decline" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">decline</a>

                    <span class="ring_1"></span>
                    <span class="tickers"></span>
                    <figure class="user">
                        <img src="images/user.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div id="gc">
                    <span class="username">Game username</span>
                    <span class="level">Level: intermediate</span>
                    <span class="wager">Wager
            <span class="count">500</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="sp">sp
            <span class="count">45%</span>
                    <span class="blink_glare"></span>
                    </span>
                    <a href="#" class="accept">accept</a>
                    <a class="decline" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">decline</a>

                    <span class="ring_1"></span>
                    <span class="tickers"></span>
                    <figure class="user">
                        <img src="images/user.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: false
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry the text " here is the working code" is itself has a link to my code.

Comment: you need to post the code here. nobody's gonna go to your site and view the source and check the code

Comment: Please dump the code in your question.

Comment: it's not allowing me to put the code here.

Comment: well that's something new. how are you trying to post it? just edit your question and paste it in the question. don't try to copy it in the comments.

Comment: I just successfully added the code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are not calling your `elip` function for other slides.
Only single slide is visible initially and elipText uses element dimensions to calculate letter position.

You could call this function when slide toggles:

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    elip();
});
```